# How to find delta for same number and name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, lead

I have the below dataframe and I need to subtract and find the delta between next quater and current quater plus next to next quater and current quater.

Input data:

```
Number Name Year Quater value
1      an   2018 1      2.5
2      bn   2018 1      1.5
1      an   2018 2      3.5
2      bn   2018 2      4.5
1      an   2018 3      4.5
1      an   2018 4      2.5
2      bn   2018 4      1.5
1      an   2019 1      5.5
2      bn   2019 1      1.5
```

Output: `d_1` is the difference between next quater and current quater for same number and name, whereas `d_2` is the diff between next to next quater and current quater for same number and name.

```
Number Name Year Quater value d_1 d_2
1      an   2018 1      2.5   1   2
2      bn   2018 1      1.5   3   
1      an   2018 2      3.5   1   -1
2      bn   2018 2      4.5       -3
1      an   2018 3      4.5   -2  1
1      an   2018 4      2.5   3
2      bn   2018 4      1.5   0
1      an   2019 1      5.5  
2      bn   2019 1      1.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure the data is correctly sorted:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['Year', 'Quater'])
```

Then use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to calculate the differences between rows:

```
df['d_1'] = df.groupby(['Number', 'Name'])['value'].diff(periods=-1) * -1
df['d_2'] = df.groupby(['Number', 'Name'])['value'].diff(periods=-2) * -1
df = df.fillna(0.0)
```

Result:

```
Number  Name  Year  Quater  value   d_1   d_2
     1    an  2018       1    2.5   1.0   2.0
     2    bn  2018       1    1.5   3.0  -0.0
     1    an  2018       2    3.5   1.0  -1.0
     2    bn  2018       2    4.5  -3.0  -3.0
     1    an  2018       3    4.5  -2.0   1.0
     1    an  2018       4    2.5   3.0   0.0
     2    bn  2018       4    1.5  -0.0   0.0
     1    an  2019       1    5.5   0.0   0.0
     2    bn  2019       1    1.5   0.0   0.0
```

---

**Edit:**

If missing values should be considered as well, the best way is to [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) the dataframe first to add any missing rows.

First, add a new column `date` and resample the dataframe:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year'].astype(str) + 'Q' + df['Quater'].astype(str))
df = df.set_index('date').groupby(['Number', 'Name']).resample('Q').first().drop(['Name', 'Number'], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Now we have:

```
Number  Name          date  Year  Quater  value
     1    an    2018-03-31  2018     1.0    2.5
     1    an    2018-06-30  2018     2.0    3.5
     1    an    2018-09-30  2018     3.0    4.5
     1    an    2018-12-31  2018     4.0    2.5
     1    an    2019-03-31  2019     1.0    5.5
     2    bn    2018-03-31  2018     1.0    1.5
     2    bn    2018-06-30  2018     2.0    4.5
     2    bn    2018-09-30   NaN     NaN    NaN
     2    bn    2018-12-31  2018     4.0    1.5
     2    bn    2019-03-31  2019     1.0    1.5
```

Now apply the same `groupby` and `diff` as above as well as dropping extra rows, the `date` column and sort the result:

```
df['d_1'] = df.groupby(['Number', 'Name'])['value'].diff(periods=-1) * -1
df['d_2'] = df.groupby(['Number', 'Name'])['value'].diff(periods=-2) * -1
df.dropna(subset=['Year']).fillna(0.0).sort_values(by=['Year', 'Quater']).drop('date', axis=1)
```

The `fillna` can be skipped if you prefer to keep the NaNs.

Comment: Thanks shaido, one error - 2 bn has quater 3 entry missing but going by this logic we subtract q4 with q2 , is there any way to control it  so we get missing value there insteqad?

Comment: @user3222101: Yes, it is possible. I edited the answer and added on how it can be done.

Comment: thank you shaido, please could you explain this code
df = df.set_index('date').groupby(['Number', 'Name']).resample('Q').first().drop(['Name', 'Number'], axis=1).reset_index()

Comment: @user3222101: It will simply group by the Number and Name columns and resample quarterly. In this case, it will add a new row as shown in the answer. The `.drop(['Name', 'Number'], axis=1).reset_index()` part is simply to restructure the dataframe to be the same as before the operation.